# Can and should I use two fragments in a Activitiy

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have little bit experience with Android and I'm not sure how to resolve this design problem. Maybe someone know a good solution. I like to build an Activity which look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwQaU.png

The user should have to choice to drag the marker on the map or to enter the adress. I like to define the whole layout in XML without to extend from the map fragment.

Have someone a example how I can split the screen 80/20 with two fragments?

Are fragments are the right choice?

Comment: I would use one single fragment in this case.

Comment: One of the advantages of using fragments is that you can have more than one in a single activity.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a single fragment in this case. In your XML you'll want a LinearLayout so you can utilize weights to achieve the 80/20 you described above.

```
<LinearLayout>

   <MapFragment/>

   <EditText/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Give the linearLayout a "vertical" orientation and assign a weights of 4 and 1 to the children to split them 80/20%.

If this isn't enough to go off, let me know and I can explain further.
Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use LinearLayout and play with the layout_weight parameter on the fragments to split the screen that way. Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:name="name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:layout_height="0sp" />

<fragment
    android:name="name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0sp" />
```

I don't think you need 2 fragments for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one main LinearLayout with vertical orientation and inside set two RelativeLayout. One with map fragment and second with edittext.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_height="0sp" >
        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:background="#999">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```